# angular-file-upload - how to get URL of uploaded file

Tags: angularjs

Im trying to create a form that a user can select an image and upload as part of the entry.

I have the upload function working. When the user selects the image and presses upload it uploads to the folder on the server.

However what i need to do is somehow get the URL and use it as a parameter in the form.

Button simply calls the upload function

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="uploadProductPicture();">Upload</button>
```

Client.Controller Method

```
// Change user profile picture
    $scope.uploadProductPicture = function () {

        // Clear messages
        $scope.success = $scope.error = null;

        // Start upload
        $scope.uploaderProduct.uploadAll();

   };
```

When the user uploads the file where do i get the URL?

Added server logic

```
exports.changeProductPicture = function (req, res) {

        fs.writeFile('./modules/deals/client/img/uploads/' + req.files.file.name, req.files.file.buffer, function (uploadError) {
            if (uploadError) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'Error occurred while uploading profile picture'
                });
            } else {

                res.json({ file: req.files.file.name });

                // Set variable to file location

            }
        });

};
```

And Route

```
  app.route('/api/deals/picture')
  .post(deals.changeProductPicture);
```

Comment: Use the same server logic that writes the file to directory to return the url

Comment: Im not really sure how. Ive added the function that is called by the route but im fairly sure i have that setup wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how do you serve the image files uploaded in your server at first.
If you use `express` in your node server, you could use `express.static` module to serve the images uploaded like a normal static images.

I think the code is something like this.

### In node

```
var upload_image_dir = './modules/deals/client/img/uploads/';

// route setting
app.use('/upload-images', express.static(upload_image_dir));

// image upload handler
exports.changeProductPicture = function (req, res) {

    fs.writeFile(upload_image_dir + req.files.file.name, req.files.file.buffer, function (uploadError) {
        if (uploadError) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: 'Error occurred while uploading profile picture'
            });
        } else {
            res.json({ file: req.files.file.name,
                url_image: upload_image_dir + req.files.file.name
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Now that the client could use the url of image uploaded by extracting the json response.

I hope this example could give you some idea.